# Re-entry to USA from Canada (previously on F-1 Visa)

Tags: usa, canada, f1-visas

I am a Canadian citizen, currently back home in Canada. I completed my BFA in NYC from 2014-2018, and also finished my OPT from July 2018-July 2019. My grace period is 60 days, meaning it should've ended on September 6th, 2019. I am seeking advice on returning to the US, as a visitor, for a week or so, however this would be during my grace period. I have heard that I may have some trouble, and that it may depend on the officer at the border. I have absolutely no plans to work, or overstay, truly just a visit to see friends. Any advice on this? Has anyone experienced something similar? To add, I have no criminal history, and would have a plane/bus return ticket already booked by the time I attempt to enter.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return in F status after you leave the US.  The grace period ends when you leave.

Your proposed visit appears to be permissible in B-2 status, which is the normal tourist status that Canadians receive when they enter the US for personal reasons.  There's a chance that your recent F status will bring greater scrutiny, but if you can prove that you're visiting friends and have a home to return to in Canada, you should be admitted.

Comment: Really appreciate the advice. So, do I need to apply for a B-2 visa just for a visit to the US? Even if there is proof of return and the visit is 1-2 weeks for leisure? Or will my Canadian citizenship and previous F status just bring additional questioning? Thanks again for any help!

Comment: @elij1s you don't need a visa.  Canadians who visit for personal reasons are admitted in B-2 status without a visa.

Comment: Ah, right. I seem to have confused a visa with status. I will definitely proceed with caution if I plan a trip and will be prepared to answer additional questions from an officer. Thanks again for the insight.